# Maintaining scope of 'this' within a constructor module

Tags: javascript, module, scope

I'm trying to learn the module design pattern and I'm having trouble with scope in a nested method function. Other questions on the topic appear more advanced than what I'm doing. So, in the following code:

```
var myModule = function(){
  var myObject = {
    myArray: [],    //array of items
    addItem: function(arg){
            var item = {
                type: "example",
                value: arg
                }
            this.myArray.push(item);
        }
    }
  return myObject;
}
```

The method "addItem" doesn't seem to be adding the object to "myObject.myArray", but rather adding it to itself? Not quite sure. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

'this' is scoped to the addItem() function.  You'd need to use

```
myObject.myArray.push(item);
```

You'll see a common practice where functions will set 'this' to another variable to reference later on inside of child functions/objects.

```
var self = this;
```

or

```
var $this = this;
```

Comment: So, in this case, where should I assign "var self = this;"? It's not a property of myObject, yet placing it in myModule appears to be outside the scope I need.

Comment: That was just an example about scope and setting 'this' to a variable.  It wouldn't work in your example.

Answer (score 1):

This will work as you expect and item will be pushed to the array of the myObject.

```
var myModule = function(){
var myObject = {
    myArray: [],    //array of items
    addItem: function(arg){
            var item = {
                type: value,
                value: arg
                }
            myObject.myArray.push(item);
        }
    }
    return myObject;
}
```

Though your 'value' var is not defined in the addItem function.

Comment: Oops, that was just an example. A typo, really. Thanks for catching it. Fixing it in my example code...

Answer (score 1):

Stop trying to cheat death. just use prototype.

Something like:

```
var MyModule = function() {

    this.myArray = [];
};
MyModule.prototype.addItem = function(arg) {
    var item = {
        type : "example",
        value : arg
    };
    this.myArray.push(item);
};
```

And you would call it like:

```
var myModule = new MyModule()

myModule.addItem({
    better : 'way'
});
```